# Django login not working

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-class-based-views, django-login

I m trying to create a `login` page using `django auth.views`
But unfortunately, user is not getting logged in. I even tried logging in as superuser( Able to login using django admin). But not able to login as superuser even through my login.
Here is my `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import LoginForm
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView, RedirectView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.views.generic  import DetailView, ListView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
from django.shortcuts import redirect, resolve_url
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

from django.views.decorators.debug import sensitive_post_parameters



class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs ):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context = {'now':timezone.localtime(timezone.now(),timezone = None) }
    return context

class Login(FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        redirect_to = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
        auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
        if self.request.session.test_cookie_worked():
            self.request.session.delete_test_cookie()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters('password'))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       request.session.set_test_cookie()
       return super(Login, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)



class ProfileView(TemplateView):
    template_name='profile.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required) 

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_active:
            return super(ProfileView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)                
        else:        
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, self.srequest.path))
```

In `settings.py` I have setup values for `LOGIN_URL` and `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` as `'accounts/login'` and `'accounts/profile'` respectively.

Here is my form in the template.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input class="btn btn-danger form-control submit-btn"  type="submit" value="Login + Access Profile" />
</form>
```

> **Problem:** After typing the credentials, the url just adds a csrfmiddletoken=..... It doesnt redirect to profile page. Nor does the User gets Logged in ( because when `accounts/profile` is visited it redirects back to login page.)

Can anybody Help me with this. I m just learning Django class-based Views, authentication. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know why you've posted your views.py, you're posting to the built-in Django auth views so your own views are not used.

Comment: So, should i change action of the form ?? @DanielRoseman

Comment: Daniel Roseman is right, you are calling Django auth view. Change the actio nand also check that your url.py calls your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a custom CBV `Login(FormView)`, but in the template you have `<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">` So your Login view could not be called at POST-request. 
You should change "action" argument at least to `action="/accounts/login"` (but better use the "url" template tag)

Additional info: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/ ("url" section)

Also I am noticed a typo in `return HttpResponseRedirect('%s?next=%s' %  settings.LOGIN_URL, self.srequest.path))` - I think there  should be `self.request.path`